# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_context.t0.data.error')]

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm getting the below error:

```
"[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object 
(evaluating '_context.t0.data.error')]
screens\Hospitais.js:65:20 in Dermatologistas#getUsers"
```

in my app, can you help me ?

```
export default class Dermatologistas extends Component{
state = {
    errorMessage: null,
    users: []
  }
```

how you could see the message says the error is here

```
 getUsers = async() => {
   try{
     console.log('1')
     const response = await api.get('/auth/list')

     const { users } = response.data
     this.setState({ users })
    }catch (response){
      this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.error})
  }
}

async componentDidMount(){
  this.getUsers()
}

render(){
  const users = this.state.users
  console.log(users)
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!!this.state.errorMessage && <text>{this.state.errorMessage}</text>}
      {this.state.users.filter(user => user.speciality === 'Hospital').map(user => (
          <View key={user._id} style={{marginTop: 15, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:20}}>{user.title}</Text>
            <Text>{user.speciality}</Text>
            <Button   title = 'View Profile'onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}/>
            </View>
        ))}

    </View>
  )
}
  

}
```

Here is my api page :

```
import {create} from 'apisauce'
import {AsyncStorage} from '@react-native-community/async-storage'


const api = create({
    baseURL: 'https://wonderful-skunk-63.loca.lt'
})
```

before I added this it was workig as expected, just  showing that no token was provided and working in other pages with no auth required

```
api.addAsyncRequestTransform( request => async() => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@backend:token')

    if (token)
        request.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
})

api.addResponseTransform( response => {
    if (!response.ok) throw response
})

export default api;
```

Comment: My guess is your try block is throwing and the error is here: this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.error}).
Check the type of the response variable by printing it to the console. It might be a string.

Comment: before I added the requestTransform to get the token it was working

Comment: Is this line 65?:

this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.error})

Comment: yeah, but for some reason before I added the  requestTransform it was working just fine

Comment: From just the code you posted, I can't say for sure, but it looks like you are trying to intercept HTTP requests and adding an authentication token to them.
You can have addAsyncRequestTransform cause a server error, which causes that line in getUsers to be hit. Check the Network tab in Chrome DevTools. See if you are getting an HTTP error.

Comment: @RicardoAgra Im not using Chrome, im using expo and insomnia